# Why format bitcoin public key?

Tags: format, bitcoin, public-key

I have some questions.
Why we format public key -> uncompressed key and compressed key.

And When we use uncompressed key vs compressed key?

I think uncompressed key is too long...

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question, it might work on [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

The uncompressed key is too long, you are right.
The compressed key is the uncompressed key as Base58 data.
Satoshi decided to use Base58 because Base58 has only characters which do not look similar (Like "O" and"0"). Also Base58 strings are much smaller and more readable. There are several libraries which help you to convert data to Base58 and vice versa.